# Weird side effect when using .clone() in JPA getters (.clone() used due to SonarQube issue)

Tags: java, jpa, sonarqube

I hava a persistance problem that I don't understand.

I have a Jpa persistence class with getters and setters for each column - everything works fine - except: SonarQube marks a major issue here

```
public Timestamp getKey()
{
  return this.key;
}
```

Rule *Malicious code vulnerability - May expose internal representation by returning reference to mutable object* - the explanation suggests to add `.clone()` (and a cast is necessary). So I got

```
public Timestamp getKey()
{
  return (Timestamp) this.key.clone();
}
```

But now, persistence doesn't work anymore - when I try to create a new `DataJpa` and then `entityManager.persist(dataJpa)`, I get the following error message:

*COMMUNICATION_ERROR: General error occurred: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.openjpa.util.java$sql$Timestamp$proxy
    at com.appclient.container.startup.ClientContainerEJBFactory.createEJBException(ClientContainerEJBFactory.java:27)*

I have no idea why using `.clone()` could cause such a side effect. Why do I get this `ClassNotFoundException` when I use `.clone()` and the cast to `Timestamp`, but don't get it when I `return this.key;` directly?

Alternative question: how to change the getter so SonarQube won't complain?

Any idea? Thanks.

**Edit:** I will get this weird side effect only on `Timestamp`, not on `Date` for example.

**Edit 2:** The suggestion from the comment to use `new Timestamp(this.key.getTime());` works and removes the SonarQube issue. Not sure about performance compared to calling `.clone()`.

Comment: It seems the value is lazily loaded, thus it uses a proxy class that to you looks like the same class, but internally it isn't, and it's name is different.

Comment: @coladict But why is the getter used when creating and saving the value at all and why does this happen only when I use `.clone()`??

Comment: @outofmind Do you really need to obey SonarQube blindly? It's just a program after all. Besides it seems like a false positive.

Comment: This is a `java.sql.Timestamp`, right? Try `return new Timestamp(key.getTime());` in that getter. Another solution would be if you can make OpenJPA use Field access, instead of Property, so that it doesn't use the getter/setter. Returning the new one every time will however prevent any fetching from the cache, since that's your key.

Comment: @Kayaman if the customer wants no new major issues, I have to give good reasons or get it done. The getter just gives you a reference to the object, so afterwards there's two references on the same object, and both could update it. This wouldn't happen if I returned a clone.

Comment: @outofmind As coladict said, `Timestamp` is immutable so that's not possible. If there's a setter for the field, it's even more ridiculous. SonarQube is still just a tool, it's worrying to see people obey it like some sort of ancient god, without understanding the issues properly. The customer isn't an ancient god either, although they usually have more divine powers than lint-tools.

Comment: @Kayaman is it? what about `.setTime()`? I don't see coladict said that `java.sql.Timestamp` was immutable, and as far as I can tell it isn't immutable

Comment: @outofmind Seems like he removed his comment. Shouldn't have trusted him. Still, it seems buggy on SQ's side especially if it does that only for `Timestamp`. Both `Timestamp` and `Date` extend `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @Kayaman SQ complains about both `Timestamp` and `Date`. But the JPA issue with ClassNotFoundException happens only on `Timestamp`

Comment: @outofmind Well, they're both relying on `java.util.Date.clone()`, but `Timestamp` *is* a bit more complicated (`java.sql.Date` is essentially just a dummy subclass). Doesn't explain the root reason why the proxy class isn't found though.